# Calculating elements of a particular order

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$

To find all the elements in $(\mathbb Z_{10009}^*,\cdot)$ of order $72$ (without an exhaustive search), I have proceeded in the following manner : 
For a finite group $(X,\cdot)$ and for any a $X$, the order of $b = a^i$ is $$\ord(b) = {\ord(a)\over \gcd(\ord(a),i)}$$
The primitive root for the group is 11, so every element can be represented as a power of 11 i.e. a=11. Now using the formula mentioned above, $$72 ={\ord(a)\over \gcd(\ord(a),i)} = {10008\over \gcd(10008,i)}$$
I can find all the numbers with order 72, if I can find all *i* such that $$\gcd(10008,i) = 139$$. How to find all such i?

Is it possible to find all the elements of a group having a particular order by some other means?

Comment: Surmising that where you wrote gdc you meant $\gcd$, I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a reasonable approach.

From here, since $139$ divides $10008$ and $\gcd(10008,i)=139$, we know $i$ is divisible by $139$ and $\gcd(\frac{i}{139},\frac{10008}{139})=1$.  Since $\frac{10008}{139}=2^3 3^2$ is divisible by the primes $2$ and $3$, and only these primes, $i=139j$ for all $j$ indivisible by $2$ and $3$ or equivalently $j \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6.$

So, the elements of order $72$ are $11^{139j}$ for all $j \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$.